# word 2010 vba, counting columns

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an imported table in Word, that contains joined columns. Each line may contain 2 or more columns.
What is the best way of identifying the number of columns on a single line.
My aim, is to examine the content of column two when a line contains only two columns,(no line will ever have a single column), and ignore the content of column two then there are more than two columns on a line.

Answer (score 0):

.Rows(CR).cells.count yields the number of cells per row

```
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range
    For CR = 1 To .Rows.Count
        For Each acell In .Rows(CR).Cells
            debug.print .Rows(CR).cells.count
        next
    next
end with
```